# Use Powershell to update date fields in CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file that contains a couple of fields that are in date format. This is the header line from the csv along with the first row:

```
"id","start_time","end_time","station_id","location"
"12617954","31/07/2014 4:38:49 AM","31/07/2014 4:39:19 AM","2","tv","home"
```

The csv file has many entries and I want to convert each date to a custom format using powershell. The custom format is `yyyyMMdd-hh:mm:ss`

Have tried this so far but haven't had any success writing the results to the csv file. I'm clearly no expert but what am I doing wrong?

```
$dateformats = [string[]]("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt","dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt")
$csvfiles = Import-Csv -path "D:\new_creative.csv"
ForEach ($line in $csvfiles) {
    $starttime2 = [datetime]::ParseExact($line.start_time, $dateformats, [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,[System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None)
    $starttime2.year.ToString() + $starttime2.month.toString().PadLeft(2,"0") + $starttime2.day.toString().PadLeft(2,"0") + "-" + $starttime2.Hour.toString().PadLeft(2,"0") + ":" + $starttime2.Minute.toString().PadLeft(2,"0") + ":" + $starttime2.Second.toString().PadLeft(2,"0")
    $starttime = $line.start_time.Replace($starttime,$startime2)
}
$csvfiles | Export-Csv "D:\file2.csv" -Force -Notype
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```powershell
$csv = Import-Csv -path "D:\new_creative.csv"
$dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd-hh:mm:ss"

ForEach($r in $csv) {
  $r.start_time = [DateTime]::parse($r.start_time).ToString($dateFormat) 
  $r.end_time = [DateTime]::parse($r.end_time).ToString($dateFormat) 
}

$csv | Export-Csv "D:\file2.csv" -Force -NoType
```

Use the `ToString` method of `DateTime` to do the conversion to the format you want.

Each time you hit a `start_time` or `end_time` field, this takes that value, converts it and then overwrites it, so the end result will have your converted dates in those fields.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks very much arco444.